# Why could Bundler not find compatible versions, but I can?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, bundler, tzinfo

I'm `bundle upgrade`ing a few gems, and getting some errors I find strange:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tzinfo":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
        tzinfo (~> 1.1)

    tzinfo-data was resolved to 1.2019.2, which depends on
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
```

Wouldn't tzinfo 1.1 satisfy this? Isn't `>= 1.0.0` just a subset of `tzinfo (~> 1.1)`?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mongo":
  In Gemfile:
    mongo (~> 2.4.1)

    mongoid (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.2.1, which depends on
      mongo (< 3.0.0, >= 2.4.1)
```

Why wouldn't mongo 2.4.1 would satisfy these?

Comment: Based on the information you have shown, both dependencies should be resolvable. If this still fails, please edit your question and add your `Gemfile`, and the full `bundle upgrade` output. There might be something missing.

Answer (score 0):

`tzinfo (~> 1.1)` is just the equivalent to '>= 1.1.0, < 1.2.0'. So `>= 1.0.0` is not subset of `~> 1.1`. Using version `1.1` should help.

I don't see the reason why mongo shouldn't work in version `2.4.1`, but try to specify exact version:

`gem 'mongo', '2.4.1'`

More about `~>` in [Rubygem guides](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint).

Comment: `~> 1.1` is actually equivalent to `>= 1.1, < 2.0`. The twiddlewaka only considers the last specified version part.